# pass a value from HTML page which is not part of a form to a php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, get

I understand that the general method of passing variables between pages is to have a form, have these elements within the form, like below, and access these as `$_GET['year']` and `$_GET['dropdown']`

```
<body>
<form method="get" action="index.php">
    <select name="language">        
        <option value = "english">English</option>
        <option value = "tagalog">Tagalog</option>
    </select>
    </br>

    <select name="year">
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

However, along with passing these two variables, namely `year` and `dropdown`, I would like to pass another variable, which is not part of the form. So, although there are only two elements in the form, I would like the GET URL to look as follows

```
http://localhost:63342/ApplicationName/php/index.php?language=tagalog&year=2010&randomNumber=1932932
```

Notice the **randomNumber=1932932** at the end of the URL.

I cannot use session variables because in the same browser and for the same user, I would like different tabs to corresponding to different values.

Comment: Why can't a hiddenfield be part of the form?

Comment: Where does the randomNumber come from?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, assume it can be anything between 1 and 100.

Comment: But I mean specifically, is it generated in your JS or what?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I tried with the hidden field, as suggested by Jose Manuel Abarca Rodríguez and Kyle Hawk. But how do I generate this random number if I hardcode the HTML, as the solution is pointing to.

Comment: How are you currently generating the random number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want use things like jQuery (which is way easier than native JavaScript), you can make a simple click handler for the submit button:

```
<body>
<form method="get" action="test.php">
    <select name="language">        
        <option value = "english">English</option>
        <option value = "tagalog">Tagalog</option>
    </select>
    <select name="year">
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submitForm()">
</form>
</body>
<script>
    function submitForm() {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1); 
        var hiddenfield = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenfield.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hiddenfield.name = 'randomnumber';
        hiddenfield.value = randomNumber;

        document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].appendChild(hiddenfield);
    }
</script>
```

This will add a hiddenfield to the form before posting and add a random number between 1 - 10000 to the hiddenfield.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hidden input within the form

```
<input type="hidden" value="something" name="name" />
```

Comment: that was almost fine. I tested it out and was able to get the value of $_GET['hiddenFieldName'] as "something". But how can I dynamically generate the value to be, say a random number between 1 and 100 with hardcoded HTML.

Comment: You'll want the mt_rand() function. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_mt_rand.asp

    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo mt_rand(0, 10); ?>" />

Comment: that's a php function. I want the random number to be part of the URL, which means it should be generated before the submit button.

Comment: @PepperBoy You can use the method that Kyle suggested. The first time that the page with the form is loaded, you call the function as Kyle demonstrated. Then when you submit the form, the random number will appear in the url. You are generating the random number on page load, not form submission.

Comment: @PepperBoy if the random number is in a hidden input in a GET form, it _will_ be part of the URL.

Comment: @PepperBoy Otherwise, you will have to do it with javascript but this is far superior.

Answer (score 0):

An option you could take it is build the get method in Ajax.  Here you access all the elements from your page and pass the into your url.  This way you are not limiting your 'get parameters' to only elements within the form.  An example is shown here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Comment: Turn your idea into real code and combine it with the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GET anyway, you can use javascript to create a URL based on the inputs,  and navigate to it instead of submitting the form.

```
<body>

<select name="language" id="lang">        
    <option value = "english">English</option>
    <option value = "tagalog">Tagalog</option>
</select>
</br>
<select name="year" id="year">
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="nav()" value="submit">

<script>
    function nav(){
        var url = 'index.php?';
        var ids = ['lang', 'year'];
        var input;
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            input = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
            url += encodeURIComponent(input.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(input.value) + '&';
        };
        url += 'randomNumber=' + 1932932; // generate a number here
        document.location = url;
    }
</script>
</body>
```